# Какой шаблон проектирования используется, когда в адресной строке нет get-параметров?

Tags: php, mvc

Здравствуйте! Разбираюсь сейчас с шаблонами проектирования для веб. Не могу понять, какой шаблон используется, например, на #ХэшКоде. То есть, в адресной строке нет никаких get-параметров, как будто мы зашли в index, лежащий в каталоге - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/
Если используется MVC, то как это реализовано? Если что-то другое, то подскажите, пожалуйста!

Comment: @Torawhit, адресная строка вообще никак не связана с шаблонами проектирования.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Курите [.htaccess](http://www.htaccess.net.ru/doc/mod_rewrite/RewriteRule.php)

Answer (score 0):

Такой же шаблон проектирования, как в случае наличия параметров в GET. Выполняются либо настройки по умолчанию, либо отрабатывают роуты. Рекомендую смотреть код и то как оно работает в известных фреймворках.

Comment: @Etki, @Павел Вершинин, @VasyOk спасибо!